# How to edit data SQLDeveloper + Workspace Manager

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

please I want to know how to CRUD a versioned table with Oracle WM using SQL Developer? A lot of tables/views are generated but I don't know which table is correct for CRUD operations.
Please, I don't want to manually write SQL commands to insert/delete/update records.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't do CRUD operations directly on any of the tables.  You would perform those operations on the view that has the original name of the table.

When you version-enable the table `FOO`, you end up with a view named `FOO` and a number of additional objects.  The original table `FOO` will have been renamed `FOO_LT` and will have a few additional columns added.  You wouldn't want to do DML directly on `FOO_LT`, though, you'd want to go through the `FOO` view and let the `INSTEAD OF` triggers handle the updates to the various underlying tables.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But is there a convenient interface to edit data instead of using directly SQL?